# How to concatenate macrovalues

Tags: c-preprocessor

First of all: this is concerning to build AQL-database scrips for DB++ (from ASA concept). These scrips use the **c-preprocessor** from "Kerninghan Ritchie (1978)". So I can't change it.

---

I try to build a dependent definition.

I define "MONTH" with "202207". Then I want automatically define "MONTH_MAX" with "20220731" and "MONTH_MIN" with "20220700".

Or better a macro "MONTH_MAX(month) month31"

I tried

```
#define MONTH 202207
#define MONTH_MAX MONTH31
#define MONTH_MIN MONTH00
```

but then "MONTH_MIN" becomes "MONTH00" instead of "20220700".

```
#define MONTH_MIN(month) month00
#define MONTH 202207
```

So I got "month00" if I call MONTH_MIN(MONTH)

`#define MONTH_MIN(month) month ## 00` let to `202207 ## 00`

---

Following works:

```
#define FILE(name) '/db/name'
FILE(customers)
```

So `FILE(customers)` is replaced with `'/db/customes'`.

---

At the end it looks like (db-syntax isn't important)

"query.dbq":

```
#define FILE(name) '/db/name'

#define MIN_MONTH(month) month00

#define KTNR  134256
#define MONTH 202107

(
  FILE(customers)
    ::
  cst_ktnr == KTNR
    %%
  cst_nr
  cst_ktnr
)
  **
(
  FILE(orders)
    ::
  cst_last_order <= MIN_MONTH(MONTH)  // here I need 20210700
    %%
  cst_nr = ord_customer
)
```

It becomes

```
#line 1 ""
// 7 empty lines
(
  '/db/customers'
    ::
  cst_ktnr == 134256
    %%
  cst_nr
  cst_ktnr
)
  **
(
  '/db/orders'
    ::
  cst_last_order <= month00  // here I need 20210700
    %%
  cst_nr == ord_customer
)
```

I tried

```
#define MIN_MONTH(month) month##00     -->    202107##00
#define MIN_MONTH(month) month ## 00   -->    202107 ## 00
#define MIN_MONTH(month) month00       -->    month00
```

Comment: What does `MIN_MONTH(202107)` give you when it's defined as `month##00` ?

Comment: The I get `202107##00`.

Comment: Your preprocessor must be broken then; I get `20210700`.  The problem is in passing a macro in as an argument to another macro.

Comment: The value of the other macro is passed. `MIN_MONTH(MONTH)` gives `202107##00` too (if `#define MONTH 202107`). So I think the "##" operator doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any info on the preprocessor implementation?

Comment: I don't think so. :(

Comment: Does `#define MONTH_MAX MONTH/**/31` works ? Can you use arithmetic? What about `#define MONTH_MAX (MONTH*100+31)`? There is no notion - does `MONTH` really represent a month and do you intent to handle different number of days in each month? Do you have `#ifdef` and `#if`? What else can you tell us about the preprocessor? `the c-preprocessor from "Kerninghan Ritchie (1978)` Is this the year of the program you are using as written by Ritchie? Do you have the source code? How do you know it's _exactly that version_ of the preprocessor? Ritchie has written _a book_  in that 1978.

Comment: @KamilCuk - `#define MONTH_MAX (MONTH*100+31)` does work! With `#define MONTH 202207` I get `(202207*100+31)`. This works. - Thanks! You can give it as answer.

Comment: If somebody is interested in this DB: http://www.concept-asa.de/index_gb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use arithmetics, then:

```
#define MONTH_MAX (MONTH*100+31)
```